# how to call a method in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pug

Below is my jade file

```
.criteria(ng-show="$index <= maxCriteriaShow")
    input#checkbox-1.checkbox-custom(name='checkbox-1', 
      type='checkbox', 
      checked='', ng-model='criteria.checked')
    label.checkbox-custom-label(for='checkbox-1') 
      span(translate="{{Key}}")
```

In the above code `$scope.Key` gets initialized only when we call `_getKey()` method. Is there a way to call these method somewhere before.

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. What are you trying to achieve ? What is `_getKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways to initialize view model values.

### ng-init

Assuming that your `$scope` has exposed the `_getKey` method via `$scope._getKey = function(){ ... };`, you can do it like this

```
div(ng-init="_getKey()")
```

## OR

### calling from inside a view controller

This assumes that you're using a view controller

**declaring the view controller**

```
div(ng-controller="ViewController")
    span(translate="{{key}}")
```

**calling in the view controller**

```
.controller( 'ViewController', function( $scope ){

    _getKey = function(){
        //do something
        $scope.key = someValue;
    }

    //do more stuff to your controller

    _getKey()
}
```